# Gmail transforms and removes HTML and CSS contents

Tags: php, html, css, email, gmail

I'm working on a WebApp which generates some QR codes and sends them by mail to the client.

I have read that to let gmail interprets correctly the CSS of the mail etc.. I should include it in the HTML in the inline way.

this is my code :

```
// Headers 
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'To: ' . $qremail . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Mehdi' . "\r\n";

$qr_images_url = "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . "/GPAYME-ticket/" . $PNG_WEB_DIR;

// Loop on the QR images 

$html_email .= "<img src='" . $qr_images_url . $qr_image_name . "' style='min-width: 225px; width: 225px; max-width: 225px; min-height: 225px; height: 225px; max-height: 225px; margin-right: 15px; border: 2px solid #D8D4D4; margin-bottom: 15px;' />";

// END of the Loop on the QR images 

mail($email, $subject, $html_email, $headers);
```

and It sends the mail after that.

So the `<img />` tags should be something like :

```
<img src="http://croisentoi.com/GPAYME-ticket/QRTemp/Qr-Ticket-60ac6339aa0c9cb6121160d55f769882.png" style="min-width:225px;width:225px;max-width:225px;min-height:225px;min-height:225px;max-height:225px;margin-right:15px;border:2px solid #d8d4d4;margin-bottom:15px">
```

When The mail is received there is actually 5 cases of the Gmail interpretaion of the `<img />` tags in it's content :

**1. Everything works fine :** `<img src="http://croisentoi.com/GPAYME-ticket/QRTemp/Qr-Ticket-60ac6339aa0c9cb6121160d55f769882.png" style="min-width:225px;width:225px;max-width:225px;min-height:225px;min-height:225px;max-height:225px;margin-right:15px;border:2px solid #d8d4d4;margin-bottom:15px">`

**2. The image source url property is removed :** `<img style="min-width:225px;width:225px;max-width:225px;min-height:225px;min-height:225px;max-height:225px;margin-right:15px;border:2px solid #d8d4d4;margin-bottom:15px">`

**3. The style property is removed :** `<img src="http://croisentoi.com/GPAYME-ticket/QRTemp/Qr-Ticket-19cde597bca16405b41cb8e3d3391d77.png">`

**4. Gmail adds an extra character in the source url property `+` in this case (/G+PAYME instead of /GPAYME) :** `<img src="http://croisentoi.com/G+PAYME-ticket/QRTemp/Qr-Ticket-368940b3754eb9c2b0fd57285efc9535.png" style="min-width:225px;width:225px;max-width:225px;min-height:225px;min-height:225px;max-height:225px;margin-right:15px;border:2px solid #d8d4d4;margin-bottom:15px">`

**5. Gmail adds an extra space in the css inside the style property in this case (width:2 25px; instead of width:225px;) :** `<img src="http://croisentoi.com/GPAYME-ticket/QRTemp/Qr-Ticket-368940b3754eb9c2b0fd57285efc9535.png" style="min-width:225px;width:2 25px;max-width:225px;min-height:225px;min-height:225px;max-height:225px;margin-right:15px;border:2px solid #d8d4d4;margin-bottom:15px">`

***p.s : For clarification purposes I have removed the extra urls added by gmail in the `<img src=`***

Do you please have any idea about this ?? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are sending emails without taking the (base64 encoded?) max line width into account. This way some whitespace get's inserted somewhere, or parts get missing.

If this is the case, you can explain all your examples:

1. No split, all on one line
2. space in `src` attribute name (i.e. "`s rc`")
3. space in `style` attribute name (i.e. "`st lye`")
4. space in `src` attribute value (an URL encoded space is a +)
5. space in `style` attribute value

Comment: Thank you. I have just added in the $headers `Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64` and still have this issue..

Comment: Are the base64 lines no longer than 76 characters? (78 including `\r\n`)

Comment: Yes it is. I have just tested with bit.ly shorten urls and it happens for gmail to remove completely the `src` property..

Comment: any solution to this issue? I'm having the same problem